# syntastic - Display both jslint and jshint errors

Tags: vim, jslint, jshint, syntastic

I just configured my Vim to used Syntastic - which works great !
I use it for javascript validation.

I have two linters installed: jslint and jshint, and I intend to keep the two. But Syntastic does not seem to want to report errors from the two at the same time: I get first errors from jshint, and then only jslint when I fixed the previous ones.

Any way I could have the two at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `g:syntastic_aggregate_errors` option to 1 (it's default value is 0):

```
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
```

This is from documentation:

> When enabled, syntastic runs all checkers that apply to the current filetype,
>   then aggregates errors found by all checkers and displays them. When disabled,
>   syntastic runs each checker in turn, and stops to display the results the first
>   time a checker finds any errors.